# What are the API Permissions necessary to start Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-data-factory

I would need to start an Azure Data Factory pipeline from REST API as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun#code-try-0

I have created an AAD app, and given it the *Azure Service Management* API Permission. However when the client through the OAuth2 Implicit flow receives an id_token and invokes that API to start a pipeline I get

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "The access token is invalid."
    }
}
```

Am i using proper API pemrission? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use OAuth2 flow to get the token to call the REST API, the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) is more suitable than the Implicit flow in this case.

Please follow the steps below.

1.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret).

2.Navigate to the data factory -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> add your AD App as an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor`, `Owner`, `Data Factory Contributor`, details follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal).

3.In the postman, follow the screenshot below, fix the request body got from step 1, then use the token to call REST API, it will work fine.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=<client_id>
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&client_secret=<client_secret>
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It works. The problem was that the doc suggests to use Implicit Flow grant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/createrun#security. Why does it suggest Implicit instead Client_Credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I cant test it right now but I would assume that having Data Factory Contributor should be enough for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#data-factory-contributor

[image]

Comment: thanks. But my point is to give an app the proper API permissions in AAD. And call it via REST using an OAuth2 flow. Azure DF Contributor is a RBAC role that I do not know how to connect to the API permission of the app.